# Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I got this exception when the first time I tried to connect my new ubuntu by ssh. I tried to search from google, but no luck until now. 
Is there anyone who had the same problem before.

Answer (score 5):

Is the sshd server running?  Set to accept nonlocal connections (check /etc/sshd/sshd_config)?  Do you have a local firewall (iptables) blocking it?  If you're trying to go through a router of some sort, does the router have a firewall blocking it?

By default, the OpenSSH server logs to the AUTH facility of syslog,
All the details of ssh login attempts will be saved in your /var/log/auth.log file. Check it.

This can occur due to Authentication refused from the other end due to bad permissions in the key files.Recreate the ssh_host_dsa_key and ssh_host_rsa_key if needed(ssh-keygen -t 'dsa/rsa') and overwrite these files in /etc/ssh.Hope this helps

Comment: I just tried "ssh localhost" and got this exception. However, I have the other 3 ubuntu virtual machine working well, I don't know why, maybe I'll have to reinstall this one? Though I don't really want to do this...

Comment: If `sshd` wasn't running he would get 'connection refused', not 'connection reset'.

Answer (score 3):

'Connection reset by peer' usually means that you have written to a connection that has already been closed by the peer. Alternatively the peer has deliberately reset it, but that is pretty rare.

Probably you have sent something the peer doesn't understand so it has given up. Are you sure it really is SSH at the other end?